# Finding average price of multiple trades with different entry price and lots considering swaps and commissions

Tags: mql4, mql5

I got this Mql4 code to find the average price. How can I add Swaps and commission to get the true break even price

```
double lotsAndPrices(int magic, int orderType) {
   double lotsByPrice = 0;
   double orderLots = 0;
   for (int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      Sleep(1);
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) {
         if (OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && orderType == OrderType() && magic == OrderMagicNumber() ) {
             lotsByPrice += OrderOpenPrice() * OrderLots();
             orderLots += OrderLots();   
         }
      }
   }
   if (orderLots > 0.0) lotsByPrice = NormalizeDouble(lotsByPrice / orderLots, Digits);
   return (lotsByPrice);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lotsByPrice += (OrderOpenPrice() * OrderLots()) + OrderCommission() + OrderSwap();
```